# Ionic platform : OTP sms auto verify

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I used cordova-plugin-sms for get sms on arrive event, but problem is that the plugin is not working on some devices and i didn't get any error in device. I have tested on latest device but not working. Please guide me

**Ionic**:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)

Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
```

**Cordova**:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, ios 4.5.5

Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3,

cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 14 other plugins)
```

**System**:

```
ios-deploy : 2.0.0

NodeJS     : v8.11.4 (/usr/local/bin/node)

npm        : 5.6.0

OS         : macOS High Sierra

Xcode      : Xcode 9.0
```

Comment: Could you add the code for the onSMSArrive event ?

Comment: yes i have added code as per plugin document @DelwynPinto

Comment: I meant add the code in the question.

Comment: show your effort here so we can help you.